# React-Modal how to pass data of a single json element

Tags: reactjs

i have a call (get) in axios with 3 object jeson, so, i need to click on a object and show more info in a modal..

i'm using react-modal and onClick function that open the modal..

What i can do to select for example item 1 from json file and show more info?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include more details. In particular, you should give a minimal, complete working example to show what you have done so far. Then show any error messages or ask a specific question about what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the json object into the modal as a prop:

```
<Modal object={object} />
```

Then access it in the Modal by this.props.object

Comment: So, in my case is <Modal data={this.props.object} /> and after, into modal i can do this: this.props.object.name ect?

Comment: My json is saved on this.state.object

Comment: If your object is saved on this.state.object, you can pass it into the modal by: <Modal data={this.state.object} />, then you can access it in the modal as this.props.data